# automatic weights won't connect skeleton to mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a mesh and constructed a skeleton from armatures, single bone & extruding, inside the mesh. I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, I click on "set parent to- with automatic weights". In every tutorial I watched this connects mesh and skeleton like magic, yet in my it does literally nothing.  I move the skeleton in pose mode, nothing, only the bones move.  I only found one person having the same problem as me and the question wasn't answered.

`.blend` file available here: https://ufile.io/304451 (apologizes for the crappy site).  This is after I used automatic weights.

I also tried with really simple things like a cube scaled to be a door and a single armature. still nothing.

Comment: It is working perfectly, but your mesh is in several parts. Select all these parts (body and legs), then shift select the armature and use ctrl+P

Comment: thanks! it seems the problem was i didn't have the mesh selected at the same time as the skeleton, which apparently is required.

Comment: Yes it is required. Many operations (if not all) need to know with/from which elements (objects, vertices, ....) they can applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Select all you mesh parts
2. Select your armature while selecting the mesh using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick
3. Hit <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose `With Automatic Weighting`

And all will be good as shown below:

[image]

As @lemon mentioned, although it will work without joining the mesh parts together, but it's better to join the mesh parts together then apply the parenting to use the dog as one object instead of having many objects representing one object as this will avoid a lot of mess. To join the mesh parts select all mesh parts using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>